# Content type creation in visual studio - title field

Tags: content-type, visual-studio

I want to create content type based on Element content type, which has only one field - Title. I'd like to modify this field's display name. How can I find the GUID of title field from base content type, so I can reference it in FieldRefs element and modify display name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you can use the Server Explorer to inspect the fields of the content type.

[image: Server Explorer]

You can also do the same thing (actually, even more) using a stand-alone application named [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I find your answer most helpful, since I don't have to leave visual studio :P

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a standard Title field from an OOTB content type, there is a simple way to fetch it: just use [SPBuiltInFieldId.Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.title.aspx) field:

> PS> [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::Title
>
> ### Guid
>
> fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247

It could be done from code or from PS, as illustrated above.

Answer (score 1):

All base fields are defined in a feature :

```
14\Templates\Features\fields\elements.xml
```

Just search for "Title" and you will find the Title column and its guid.

A side note :

This file and `14\Templates\Features\ctypes\elements.xml` for content types, are gold mines to understand and discover some undocumented ways of working with fields and/or content types